# How to set the ReadBufferSize on .NET serial port

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port

So, I am creating a VB.NET program that listens to a serial port.  I was using this

```
Dim WithEvents ptr_SerialPort As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
...
 ptr_SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort(serialportname, baudrate,parity, databits, stopbits)
```

which worked fine until i realized that I am overrunning my SerialPort.ReadBufferSize property, which is 4096, and losing data:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx

So I tried to increase the size of the buffer as follows

```
ptr_SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort(serialportname, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits)
ptr_SerialPort.ReadBufferSize = 2000000
```

But I get the error "can't set the buffer size while it's open".  Which is reasonable, so I tried this:

```
ptr_SerialPort = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(serialportname, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits)
ptr_SerialPort.ReadBufferSize = 2000000
ptr_SerialPort.Open()
```

Well, this results in a Serial port that does NOT receive data... I guess that My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort is doing more than just instantiating it, and what I have above is a serial port object that is not connected to my hardware.  So, my question is... how do I open a serial port on my PC, *and* specify the ReadBufferSize property??

Thanks very much!

Comment: The more eco-friendly option is to don't change it all but instead have your program deal with blocks at a time rather than one big buffer

Comment: I find "eco-friendly" amusing... however I only implement an event handler, don't have that kind of control, at least without drastic change in approach.  I also don't have control of the sender (at this point), to work in blocks.  So first I'd like to increase my buffer size.  I ought to be able to.

Comment: Serial comms works with the UART and sends data in blocks with the appropriate flow control regardless of whether it is c# or c++; Windows; DOS or good-ol' Dragon 64 computers.  There is no need to modify the sender just to use blocks.

Comment: Also try increasing it by a more reasonable amount 2000000 is a little excessive. Try multiples of 1028

Comment: What I am looking for is a couple of working of lines of code to set ReadBufferSize, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, oddly

```
ptr_SerialPort = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(serialportname, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits)
ptr_SerialPort.ReadBufferSize = 2000000
ptr_SerialPort.Open()
```

is now working... so this is the way to do it after all.  It must have been some intermittent problem on the other end that fooled me.  Thanks for the answers, sorry to take your time.

Comment: Clearly you have not found the real reason and this is not an answer.  Setting the Handshake property is very rarely optional, use RequestToSend.